# Can't catch exception std::stoi

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

Whenever I input anything other than an integer, I was hoping for the catch block to execute but instead I get this error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x002D0C39 in A03.exe: Stack cookie instrumentation code detected a stack-based buffer overrun. occurred

which takes me to:

> Exception thrown at 0x76D44192 in A03.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::invalid_argument at memory location 0x0116D83C.
>
> Unhandled exception at 0x000608B9 in A03.exe: Stack cookie instrumentation code detected a stack-based buffer overrun.

I've tried varieties of catch blocks and exceptions with the same error. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

Here is the code:

```cpp
int main() {
    while (true) {
        std::string input;
        int num = 0;

        std::cout << "What number do you want to show?";
        std::cin >> input;
        try 
        {
            num = std::stoi(input);
            if (num >= 0 && num < 10)
            {
                std::cout << "FILLER: This will draw the number";

                exit(0);
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "FILLER: This is the else";
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        catch (std::runtime_error e) 
        {
            std::cout << e.what();
            //std::cout << "That is not a valid number." << '\n';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**: Edited the exception handler, but still erroring:

```cpp
int main() {
    while (true) {
        std::string input;
        int num = 0;

        std::cout << "What number do you want to show?";
        std::cin >> input;
        try 
        {
            num = std::stoi(input);
            if (num >= 0 && num < 10)
            {
                std::cout << "FILLER: This will draw the number";

                exit(0);
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "FILLER: This is the else";
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        catch (std::invalid_argument &e) 
        {
            std::cout << e.what();
            //std::cout << "That is not a valid number." << '\n';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Looks good to me](https://ideone.com/RwQdMy). Bug must be elsewhere or I accidentally fixed the problem when adding stuff to make it compile. I recommend making a [mcve].

Comment: Sounds to me as if something is wrong with `input`.

Comment: I've added the full main function for better clarification.

Comment: Note: `stoi` doesn't throw `runtime_error`s. Recut of previous [Looks good to me](https://ideone.com/FIY9fX). Please add what you are using for input to the question, and to complete things add the headers you used. Sometimes it matters.

Comment: I've tried inputting individual letters 'd', multiple letters like 'dd', and special characters like '!'.

Output Error in the debug:
Exception thrown at 0x76D44192 in A03.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::invalid_argument at memory location 0x0116D83C.
Unhandled exception at 0x000608B9 in A03.exe: Stack cookie instrumentation code detected a stack-based buffer overrun.

Comment: This sounds like a possible bug in Microsoft's implementation of `std::stoi()`.  Did you try tracing into `std::stoi()` with the debugger? You might need to file a bug report with Microsoft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception that this function throws is `std::invalid_argument`, which have the following inheritance connections: `std::exception <- std::logic_error <-std::invalid_argument`. This means you can use any of the above as the catch type (and also `...`), to catch the exception. `std::runtime_error` is not one of the options (`std::exception <- std::runtime_error`).

Change your `catch` section to:

```
catch (std::invalid_argument &e) {
    std::cout << e.what();
    //std::cout << "That is not a valid number." << '\n';
}
```

#### Read About:

[std::invalid_argument](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/invalid_argument)
[std::runtime_error](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error)
[std::exception - Exceptions tree](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception)

Comment: Thank you for this. The catch was changed but it did not solve the problem. I appreciate your help though and will definitely check the links you sent.

Comment: @guY this works perfectly fine for me, I am using g++ compiler in linux (Ubuntu 16.04), CLion. Please provide some details about your environment. It looks like a bug as RemyLebeau said.